# Sockets in Windows Phone 7 works fine in emulator but not on the phone

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7, tcp, udp, windows-phone-7.1

Im trying out the new additions of Socket-communication (TCP & UDP) in the Beta 2 refresh of Mango for Windows Phone 7.

The problem I have is that it behave differently on the emulator and on the actual phone (Samsung Omnia 7).

First I have tried UDP for several days now but with a lot of performance problems. I get very bursty sending of UDP-messages which has left me clueless.

Now Im trying TCP but here I get other problems instead. Firstly, I always instantly get a SocketResult of "Success" when running on the phone (ConnectAsync), no matter if the server is up or not. When running on the emulator I get "Connection Refused" which is more expected when there is no server running. When having the server online I first get "Success" and then "Connection Reset" when trying to use the connection. The server never gets past Accept. When running on the emulator everything works as expected.

Why is this? I know Mango is still in a Beta-release but could it be something Im missing here? I suspect my code is ok since it works fine in emulator mode. Ive tried turning off the Windows 7-firewall but that didnt do any good.

Im using a Samsung Omnia 7 with the Beta 2 refresh of Mango (7.10.7712.60). The Phone is connected and Zune is running. Do I need to upgrade any firmware as well?

Comment: Have you tested WITHOUT having Zune connected? Try both with WPConnect.exe instead of Zune, and without any cables whatsoever.

Comment: Ahhh that did help. Forgot to try that. Running from the Phone disconnected worked better. But now I get slow performace instead, 5 messages per second with NoDelay=false and whery bursty/erratic with NoDelay=true and custom throttling to one message per 100 ms. Hmmm. Thanks anyway. Add it as a real answer to I can check it off.

Comment: How are you identifying the machine you're trying to connect to from the phone?

Comment: By IP and port. The IP shown in ipconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing with Zune is rarely a good idea, as it have some networking issues. Instead consider using WPConnect.exe (found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect`).

Also, always test without a cable attached, to see how the phone reacts itself.